# Error variable 'x' of type 'myClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, restrictions

This code works fine:

```
ICriteria criteria = GetSession().CreateCriteria<MyClass>();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Where<MyClass>(x => x.Field1 >= myVariable));
```

But the following code does not work:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions        
        .Where<MyClass>(x =>          
        (x.Field1 +
        x.Field2 +
        x.Field3 +
        x.Field4) >= myVariable));
```

The above code get this error in execution:

> Variable 'x' of type 'myClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not
>   defined

Help please (sorry for my bad English).

Sara

**Edit 1**

My Temporary solution is:

```
var result = criteria.List<MyClass>();    
result.Where(x => (x.Field1 + x.Field2 + x.Field3 + x.Field4 >= myVariable));
```

and this work. I would prefer put the Where clause before selection...

**Edit 2**

The final solution is (as suggested from @mhoff):

```
var result = criteria.List<MyClass>();    
result.Where(x => this.GetSum(x) >= myVariable);

... do something ...

... ToList()


private int GetSum(MyClass x) {
 return (x.Field1 + x.Field2 + x.Field3 + x.Field4);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this isn't the `Where` method form Linq. Is it something you've written or from a library you're using? It looks like it's doing something funky to the expression you're passing it.

Comment: @applechewer: only GetSession() is method written by me. Everything else are NHibernate methods.

Comment: this has nothing to do with multiline? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653703/can-a-c-sharp-lambda-function-be-more-than-one-line should not, just a guess. you could try adding {} to the lambda just to make sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243890/nhibernate-restriction-with-sum-of-2-columns

Comment: @AndreasReiff: I get the same error even when it is in line

Comment: @nemesv: with code
criteria.Add(Expression.Sql("Column1 > (Column2 + Column3)"));
works, but I don't want use the name of columns.

Comment: @sara: The other solution for that page might work, basically manually building the expression tree.

Comment: How is Restrictions.Where defined in terms of typing?

Comment: My understanding is that by doing .List<MyClass> you are evaluating at this point and the .Where is now regular LINQ. This is not what I was expecting. I want SQL, not LINQ, to handle it in the evaluation of the Criteria. What is the point of Restrictions.Where<>() if you can't seemingly use it in any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

If `Restictions` is an `IEnumerable` of `MyClass` then try to divide add and select:

```
var v = Restrictions
    .Where(x =>(x.Field1 + x.Field2 +  x.Field3 + x.Field4) >= myVariable));

criteria.Add(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about turning your calculation into a property (this also has the benefit of encapsulating MyClass specifics):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int GetSum
    {
        get { return Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4; }
    }
}

criteria.Add(Restrictions.Where<MyClass>(x => x.GetSum > myVariable));
```

Comment: `criteria.Add(Restrictions.Where<MyClass>(x => this.GetSum(x) > myVariable));
private int GetSum(MyClass x) {
  return (x.Field1 + x.Field2 + x.Field3 + x.Field4);
}` I have the same error :-( But is good idea move the sum (also because I reuse it)

Comment: I create a method because I have to pass a parameter (MyClass) and then put `x.Field1`+ `x.Field2` + etc

Comment: Why not simply `x => x.GetSum` - no need to pass "x" to "this.GetSum"

Comment: But `GetSum` not knows `Field1`, `Field2`, etc that are property of MyClass

Comment: `GetSum` resides in class `MyClass`, right? `Field1/2..` are all properties on `MyClass`? Please try it out in our environment.

Comment: Sorry, `GetSum` isn't in MyClass because `MyClass` is an autogenerated mapping class and I don't want to touch.

Comment: That... really isn't okay. What if you have a parameter? Can't be a property. So Restrictions.Where<MyClass>(x => x.Foo(param))) isn't possible? Why? That's makes no sense.

Comment: @user999999928 If you have a parameter other than `x` needed in the `GetSum` calculation, then you are right, `GetSum` can't be a property. But, please look at the original example which states that the Fields all resides in `MyClass`. @sara later stated that the class was autogenerated, and as such didn't leave room for the addition of `GetSum` - in this case `GetSum` could be formulated as an `MyClass` extension method in a static utility class.